# How does the Western States 100 choose the qualifying time for 100Ks?

Tags: running

The Western States 100 race has a qualifying cutoff time for its 100K qualifying races (https://www.wser.org/qualifying-races/) and none for 100 mile races. For 100K races, how do they determine what that qualifying time is? Is it based on past results, an effort computation based on the route, or something else?